# remove duplicate and if it is not duplicate, change its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects :

```
[0] [object Object]
   id: green
   selectable: false
[1] [object Object]
   id: green
   selectable: false
[2] [object Object]
   id: red
   selectable: true
```

what I want to do is,

- if array includes a duplicate (like green), remove the duplicate and keep one of them,
- if array does not include a duplicate (like "red"), keep it and change its value ("selectable" from "true" to "false")

Thank you!

This is what I tried so far :

```
function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
    var newArray = [];
    var lookupObject  = {};
    for(var i in originalArray) {
       lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
    }
    for(i in lookupObject) {
        newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

I can remove the duplicates but I could not find a way to edit the "non-duplicate" one

Comment: *"Thank you"*: hold on... We expect an attempt from your side, and a description of why you cannot make it work. Please show your efforts. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add your code in it as a runnable snippet (use the toolbar button in the editor). Make sure it runs and demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I just updated it, I am only looking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend your function so that your second loop would iterate over the original array, and then:

- If the iterated object is the same as in the lookup object, it means it was only encountered once, and so its selectable property should be set to `false`. You can do that for instance with `Object.assign`.
- If the iterated object is not the same as in the lookup object, it means there is still another object following with the same id, and so we should only add it once: you can add it *now* and then destroy the relevant content of the lookup object, so you will not match it again.

Here is how that would look:

```js
function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
    let newArray = [];
    let lookupObject  = {};
    for(let obj of originalArray) {
       lookupObject[obj[prop]] = obj;
    }
    for (let obj of originalArray) {
        let match = lookupObject[obj[prop]];
        if (match === obj) { // unique id
            newArray.push(Object.assign({}, obj, { selectable: false }));
        } else if (match) { // first occurrence of non-unique id
            newArray.push(obj); // duplicate is added only once
            lookupObject[obj[prop]] = null; // avoid adding it again.
        } 
    }
    return newArray;
}

let arr = [{
   id: "green",
   selectable: false
}, {
   id: "green",
   selectable: false
}, {
   id: "red",
   selectable: true
}];

let res = removeDuplicates(arr, "id");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dom it 2 steps: First I'm looking for the colors with double entries than I build the new array.
Going with foreach through the colors I look if a new cols-array is this id (color) included. If not than push it to it. Otherwise push it to the new double-array if it's not there.
Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to go over the colors-array and push the entry (with changed selectable) to the new result-array if it's not a double. For double look if it's in the new doubleUsed-array. If not push it to the result and push the id to the doubleUsed-array. Otherwise continue without doing anything.

```js
let colors = [{ id: 'green', selectable: false }, { id: 'green', selectable: false }, { id: 'red', selectable: true}];

let cols = [];
let double = []
colors.forEach(({id}) => {
  if (!cols.includes(id))
      cols.push(id);
  else if (!double.includes(id))
      double.push(id);
});

let doubleUsed = [];
let result = colors.reduce((acc,cur) => {
    if (!double.includes(cur.id))
        acc.push({id: cur.id, selectable: false});
    else if (!doubleUsed.includes(cur.id)) {
        acc.push(cur);
        doubleUsed.push(cur.id);
    }
    return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```